Why is GitHub Actions sometimes not incrementing my build number?
I have the issue that GitHub Actions sometimes increases my build number and sometimes does not. Sometimes it starts in the middle of existing numbers, sometimes in the beginning, sometimes at the end.
Example:
 v0.98.4 -> expected: v0.98.5
 GitHub: v0.98.1

This is my workflow:
name: Build and Push Docker Image on Release

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - 'release/*'

permissions:
  contents: write

jobs:
  build-and-push:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Check out code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set up Docker Buildx
        uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v1

      - name: Log in to DockerHub
        uses: docker/login-action@v1
        with:
          username: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_USERNAME }}
          password: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_PASSWORD }}

      - name: Fetch all git tags
        run: git fetch --depth=1 origin +refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*

      - name: Get the latest tag
        id: latest-tag
        run: |
          TAG=$(git describe --tags `git rev-list --tags --max-count=1`)
          echo "Latest tag is $TAG"
          echo "::set-output name=tag::${TAG}"

      - name: Increment the version
        id: next-version
        run: |
          TAG="${{ steps.latest-tag.outputs.tag }}"
          BASE_VERSION=${TAG#v} # Strip the 'v' prefix
          IFS='.' read -ra VERSION <<< "$BASE_VERSION"
          PATCH=$((VERSION[2]+1))
          NEXT_VERSION="v${VERSION[0]}.${VERSION[1]}.$PATCH"
          echo "Next version is $NEXT_VERSION"
          echo "::set-output name=version::$NEXT_VERSION"

      - name: Build the Docker image with new version
        run: |
          docker build -t xxx/yyyy:${{ steps.next-version.outputs.version }} .
          docker push xxx/yyyy:${{ steps.next-version.outputs.version }}

      - name: Tag the image as latest and push
        run: |
          docker tag xxx/yyyy:${{ steps.next-version.outputs.version }} xxx/yyyy:latest
          docker push xxx/yyyy:latest

      - name: Tag the repository with the new version
        run: |
          git tag ${{ steps.next-version.outputs.version }}
          git push origin ${{ steps.next-version.outputs.version }} --tags

For me, it seems like
      - name: Fetch all git tags
        run: git fetch --depth=1 origin +refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*

is not fetching all tags, at least not the most recent one.
But locally it works just fine.
What could be the root cause?
